# Http to Https using Nginx in aws also redirects Ipv4

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-route53, elastic-load-balancer

I need to redirect http to https,I am using Nginx to do that

I use load balancer with ACM recommended certificate.In route 53 Ipv4 used

trying to redirect http to https from below code in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {

listen 80;

  server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location / {
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
       rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
   }
         proxy_pass http://172.x1.x5.xx6:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
}
```

the problem I am facing is the public ipv4(public IP) is also redirected to https and cannot access my domain

How to not to redirect ipv4(public IP)

Comment: Do you only have one server_name setup in `nginx`?

Comment: yes..do I need to have 2

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

If you are only using `server_name` directive

> If its value does not match any server name, or the request does not
>   contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to
>   the default server for this port. In the configuration above, the
>   default server is the first one — which is nginx’s standard default
>   behaviour. It can also be set explicitly which server should be
>   default, with the default_server parameter in the listen directive...

So if you have something like this:

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    return 403;
}
server {
    listen      443 default_server;
    return 403;
}
```

Then when a request comes in and doesn't match your `server_name` then it will be defaulted to the above `server` blocks and return a `403` Forbidden result.